# Python tornado handler warnings disabling

Tags: python, tornado

I was define head method in tornado handler to check file exists:

```
def head(self, path):
    if file_isset(path):
        self.set_status(200)
    else:
        self.set_status(404)
```

But tornado writes message such as 
`WARNING:tornado.access:404 HEAD /file_name`
 to terminal.
How to disable this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the logger tornado.access prior the start of the `IOLoop` using `logging.getLogger('tornado.access').disabled = True`.

For example:

```
def main():
    logging.getLogger('tornado.access').disabled = True
    app = Application()
    http_server = HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port, address=options.host)
    IOLoop.instance().start()
```